# Is there a word that means "ignoring/dismissing a fact for disingenuous reasons"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that means "ignoring/dismissing a fact for disingenuous reasons"? Let's say a North Korean analyst wouldn't admit to the fact that the elections in North Korea aren't transparent in an argument with an American analyst, because he wants to maintain North Korea's narrative. Is there a word that describes the North Korean analyst's action?

Comment: What is wrong with: being disingenuous?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, perhaps, but would having bias suffice?

Comment: Willful ignorance would be another phrase, although it would be more a "look the other way" type meaning.

Comment: "Glossing over" is fairly similar, but not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @Bee I would have provided *wilfully ignorant* as an answer myself—it means deliberately ignoring the facts, and it more directly relevant that simply *not paying attention to something*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good answers in the comments. I will also suggest [*to turn a blind eye to*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-a-blind-eye):

> Management often turn[s] a blind eye to bullying in the workplace.

[*to shut ones eyes to*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shut-your-eyes-to-sth?q=shut++your++eyes+to++sth) is similar in meaning:

> Until now the prime minister has shut his eyes to the homelessness problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider saying that he “conveniently ignores” the truth, or that he “turns a blind eye to it”.

There’s also the idiom “elephant in the room”, referring to some huge matter which nobody wants to talk about. This most commonly comes up when a group is discussing a subject, and nobody wants to talk about one aspect because they all know it’s unresolvable. It would not be used for something which one party is actively denying.